# javascript to detect client java version

Tags: javascript

I am trying to use **deployJava** to get client java version. But `deployJava.getJREs()` is returning empty value. I am using windows 7-64bit.
Is there any way to detect client java version?

Comment: [FYI](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/deployment_advice.html#deplToolkit)

Comment: What does this have to do with JavaScript?

Answer (score 2):

firstly you need to verify whether java is enabled on client machine using below code snippet

```
navigator.javaEnabled()
```

if it returns true that means java is enabled and now futher you below code snippet

Version of Java:

```
  /**
   * @return NULL if not version found. Else return some things like: '1.6.0_31'
   */
 var JavaVersion: function()
 {
    var resutl = null;
    // Walk through the full list of mime types.
    for( var i=0,size=navigator.mimeTypes.length; i<size; i++ )
    {
        // The jpi-version is the plug-in version.  This is the best
        // version to use.
        if( (resutl = navigator.mimeTypes[i].type.match(/^application\/x-java-applet;jpi-version=(.*)$/)) !== null )
            return resutl[1];
    }
    return null;
  }
```

or you can use `javascript`

```
<script src="http://www.java.com/js/deployJava.js"></script>
<script>
var versions = deployJava.getJREs();
</script>
```

Comment: The first script throws an error, but the second one returns a version number